# Parametrized Union for python type annotations

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I'd like to define a generic type like the following

```
MyType(OtherType) := Union[SomeClass, OtherType]
```

So that instead of typing the following to annotate x:

```
x: Union[SomeClass, int]
```

I'd only have to write

```
x: MyType[int]   # or MyType(int) for what it's worth
```

Do I have to subclass `Type`? If so, how does one go about doing that?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong: `SomeClass` is a fixed existing class and `OtherType` is a type variable?

Comment: Exactly, that's it, feel free to edit if you think it could make the question clearer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly all you need is a [`TypeVar` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) like

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union


class SomeClass:
    ...


OtherType = TypeVar('OtherType')
MyType = Union[SomeClass, OtherType]


def foo(x: MyType[int]) -> int:
    return x ** 2
```

with code like this placed in `test.py` module

```sh
$ mypy test.py
```

gives me

```
test.py:13: error: Unsupported operand types for ** ("SomeClass" and "int")
test.py:13: note: Left operand is of type "Union[SomeClass, int]"
```

and with fix in `foo`

```py
def foo(x: MyType[int]) -> int:
    if isinstance(x, SomeClass):
        return 0
    return x ** 2
```

has no issues.

## Notes

If we really need this type of alias I've called it something like

```py
SomeClassOr = Union[SomeClass, OtherType]
```

since

```py
SomeClassOr[int]
```

seems more readable to me than

```py
MyClass[int]
```

## Reference

- [*mypy* docs entry](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-type-aliases)